# If $\cos x =\frac{3}{5}$ and angle $x$ terminates in the fourth quadrants, find the exact value of each of the following:

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos{x}=\frac{3}{5}$ and angle $x$ terminates in the fourth quadrants, find the exact value of each of the following:

A. $\sin{2x}$
B. $\cos{2x}$
C. $\tan {\frac{x}{2}}$

Okay, so I am going through my old exam reviews for the final exam I have this evening, and choosing problems I have trouble with. Problems like these a struggle. Could someone give me some sort of step by step? I don't need to know all A,B,and C, but maybe one of them would help. Also, if $\cos{x}=\frac{3}{5}$ and angle $x$ terminates in the fourth quadrants, wouldn't that fraction be negative?

EDIT: Thank you for all the feedback! I understand now and finally realized what I have been messing up on was so small! Will make a mental note so I don't mess up on tonights final. :)

Comment: You should be able to determine sin(x) from the given information and the identity sin(x)^2 + cos(x)^2 = 1. After that you can use double angle formulas for A and B and probably some tangent identity for C.

Comment: I would draw it on the unit circle.  Put a point at the point $(0.6,-0.8)$ From there you can get the values for $\sin{x}$ & $\tan{x}$ and use some basic trig identities to get the rest.

Comment: And a further hint: in the fourth quadrant, you are in the "bottom right" corner with angles between 3pi/2 and 2pi, so cos(x) is positive and sin(x) is negative.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Find out what is $\sin x$ and what is $\cos x$.

The following formula might be helpful.

$$\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$$

$$\cos 2x = 2 \cos^2 x -1 $$

$$ \tan 2x = \frac{2 \tan x}{1- \tan^2 x}$$

For the tangent problem,  note that

$$\tan x = \frac{2 \tan \frac{x}2}{1- \tan^2 \frac{x}2}$$

Comment: Thank you! I understand now! :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\sin^2x&=1-\cos^2x&\text{Pythagorean Identity}\\
\sin2x&=2\sin x\cos x&\text{Double Angle}\\
\cos2x&=2\cos^2x-1&\text{Double Angle}\\
\tan x&=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}&\text{Def. of $\tan x$}
\end{align}$$
You should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Cosine is positive in quadrants 1 and 4.  Think of $\cos \theta$ as the $x$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of $\theta$ intersects the unit circle, because that's one way of defining $\cos\theta$ for any angle $\theta$.  (Similarly, $\sin\theta$ is the $y$-coordinate of that point.)

Step 1:  Draw yourself a reference triangle in the correct quadrant.  In this case it would be this triangle:

[image]

Note that I labeled the angle $\overline x$ and not just $x$.  This is because the angle I drew is actually the reference angle for $x$, and not the angle $x$ itself.  This is just a subtle detail worth mentioning.

Step 2:  Find the length of the missing side so that you can get the values of the other trig functions you need.  In this case we can use the Pythagorean theorem to see that the missing side has length $4$.  **But, let's call it $-4$ because we need to move down (in the negative direction) off of the $x$-axis to "walk" across that side.**  Also, calling it $-4$ will help us keep the signs of our other trig functions straight.

Step 3:  Now that we know all three sides of this triangle, we can immediately gather the following info:
$$ \sin x = -\frac45 \qquad\qquad \tan x = \frac43 \qquad\qquad \csc x = -\frac54 \qquad\qquad \cot x = -\frac34$$
Also, we can see that $\sec x = \dfrac53$, but we can determine that just from the given fact that $\cos x = \dfrac35$.

Step 4:  Use trig identities to express $\sin 2x$, $\cos 2x$, and $\tan \dfrac x2$ in terms of some of the trig functions you found in step 3.

Comment: Thank you for this! I understand much better now:)

Answer (score 2):

Think back to the definition of $\cos(x)$ and try to draw a right angled triangle. Since $x$ is in the fourth quadrant, also know that it's in the bottom right of the plane. We also know that $\cos(x)=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$ so we have some information about our triangle. From the question, we can see that the adjacent length must be $3$ and the hypotenuse is $5$. So by Pythagoras' theorem (or by knowing about the $3,4,5$ triangle) the opposite length should be $4$. The triangle should look like the figure below. So then by using the triangle to find $\sin(x)$ and $\tan(x)$ and using the identities that @SiongThyeGoh posted, you should be able to complete the question. You might want to practice deriving those identities, too, if you think it'd help you remember them. You can do so geometrically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)=\frac{16}{25}$, so $\sin(x)=\pm\frac{4}{5}$. Since we are in the fourth quadrant, we must have $\sin(x)=-\frac 45$. Thus, $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\frac{24}{25}$.

From this, we can calculate $\cos^2(2x)=1-\sin^2(2x)=\frac{7^2}{25^2}$. Since $\sin(x)<-\cos(x)$, we know $x<-\frac{\pi}{4}$, so $2x$ is in the third quadrant. Thus, $\cos(2x)=-\frac{7}{25}$.

Finally, we can use $\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}=-\frac{4/5}{8/5}=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand much better now! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would draw it on the unit circle.  Put a point at the point $(0.6,-0.8)$ From there you can get the values for $\sin{x}$ & $\tan{x}$ and use some basic trig identities to get the rest.

[image]